# Google My business API locations list request not returning all locations

Tags: api, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am making a locations list request to the Google My Business API and passing a given account id. The list method is supposed to return a list of all locations associated to the given id. The documentation can be found here https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/list. The response is returning a list of locations as expected however there are some locations that the account has access to that are missing from the list. I have tried to investigate to see if there are any factors that could be causing this such as verification status, missing store code, duplicate GMB location, who owns/manages the location. I have not found any factor that is the cause of the issue. Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? :)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have heard from other sources that the GMB API now GBP just doesn't yield expected results infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum page size is 100 [1][2]. Are you expecting more than 100 from a single request?

[1]    https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/list

[2]    https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Nothing about my answer was rhetoric. If the user is expecting 110 locations and is only getting 100, it is a next page issue. If the user is expecting 90 locations and is only getting 80, it would be an API issue, something that happens A LOT with the GBM APIs.

Comment: If nothing about your post is rhetoric, then the "?" means that you want an answer from OP. So you have a lack of understanding, which means that the rest of your post cannot be a helpful answer. In that case you should have used your commenting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version of this API called `mybusinessbusinessinformation`, if you use a programming language to retrieve you would not have any problem to list all your locations, for example in java, suppose that  `mybusinessNotif` is an initializer of type `MyBusinessNotificationSettings` which also takes care of credentials:

```
String readMask="storeCode,regularHours,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours";
                    MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Accounts.Locations.List locationsList = mybusinessaccountLocations.accounts().locations().list(accountName).setReadMask(readMask);
                    ListLocationsResponse Response = locationsList.execute();
                    locations=Response.getLocations();

                    while (Response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                        locationsList.setPageToken(Response.getNextPageToken());
                        Response=locationsList.execute();
                        locations.addAll(Response.getLocations());              
                    }
```

In fact using `getNextPageToken()`  takes care of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in Node.js environment.

[Google Business Profile Api Method: accounts.locations.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/list#query-parameters)

Although pageSize is set as 100 by default under Query Parameters in the documentation, if you do not define pageSize when requesting, you can get up to 10 locations. I was able to solve my problem by defining an optional pageSize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).